# Use Async module with parallel function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm working with socials API and I need to be able to run those function that return the json from the socials API endpoint in parallel, in a way that only when those function are all finished I can work on their data together.

I'm trying to work with ASync module for npm but I'm not able to understand how to make it works.

Looking at the documentation I've seen this so far:

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

The problems is that I didn't understand how can I use it.
I would like to do something like this below, but without timeout and with my async functions ( these function returns me the response from the APIs ).

```
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(“Task 1”);
      callback(null, 1);
    }, 300);
  },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(“Task 2”);
      callback(null, 2);
    }, 200);
  },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(“Task 3”);
      callback(null, 3);
    }, 100);
  }
], function(error, results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Cuold you please help me ?

Comment: What is your code doing when you run it? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I tried to put my code inside the first function ( where there is console.log(task1) ) and basically I dont know how to put my function in it. I've tried different ways, but everytime I get an undefined as result. My function looks like twitterAPI(arg1,arg2,arg3,callback) and it result the data from the API endpoint. What I am expecting is the data from the Endpoint API.